# Возможно ли обойти same origin policy (SOP) для click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Для примера, есть фрейм. Я могу брать из него информацию. Как мне передать в него клик?

Сайт — во фрейме с другого доменного имени, и доступа к нему нет.

Comment: "Возможно ли обойти SOP в программах, реализующих SOP?" Странный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Я наше уже несколько решений. Например, использовать лису >5 версии или так запускать хром "C:\Users\mk\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --disable-web-security. Так же я думаю есть браузеры в которых это функция намеренно не реализуется.

Comment: ну если вы рассматриваете и такие способы, то почему бы не поднять локально сервер, у которого dns-имя будет равно вашему "родителю" фрейма, и который будет отдавать данные с настоящего сервака? тогда SOP будет соблюдаться

Comment: @BOPOH, добавь как ответ :-D